# Angular JS set value of clicked object in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat which iterates object like:

```
{
"id": 1,
"title": "Lorem Ipsum",
"base_text": "Lorem ispum",
"read_more_text": "lorem ipsum",
"show_details": false,
"button_label": "Read More",
"button_link": "",
"image": ""
},
```

Inside the ng-repeat in the html, there is a button which I want to toggle the value of that `show_details` property.

So, I have an `ng-click` handler:

```
<div class="hero-item" ng-repeat="h in dash.heroItems">
    <div>
      <h3>{{h.title}}</h3>
      <p>{{h.base_text}}</p>
      <p ng-if="h.show_details">{{h.read_more_text}}</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button ng-click="dash.showHeroDetails(h.id)">{{h.button_label}}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So I am passing the repeat instance's `ID` property.  But here I am stuck, I can't get the correct syntax for toggling that boolean property.

I have this so far:

```
  _this.showHeroDetails = function (item) {
    _this.show_details = item;
  };
```

which is clearly wrong...

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could construct a working plunker with more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From template, pass the object.

```
<div>
    <button ng-click="dash.showHeroDetails(h)">{{h.button_label}}</button>
</div>
```

In script, just toggle the value.

```
_this.showHeroDetails = function (item) {
    item.show_details = !item.show_details;
 };
```

Comment: Lol u beat me to the answer. Noticed that mistake on the parameter too :P

Comment: I was close, I knew it was something simple.  Thanks.

Comment: @wdanda Lol. Doesn't matter who answered. It always comes down to whether OP got the right answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply update the value in the  ng-click. Like this:

```
<button ng-click="h.show_details = !h.show_details">{{h.button_label}}</button>
```